# Not able to set encoded header in the request to get the token. Error - java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check

Tags: java, api, automation, rest-assured

I'm trying to generate a token by passing Base64 encoded value in the form of Header, but getting "java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check"

`RestAssured.baseURI = uri;
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
request = request.header("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedString);
Response response = request.when().post();`

Showing "java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check" exception.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RestAssured.config = config().decoderConfig(decoderConfig().useNoWrapForInflatedStreams(true));
```